# Print y-axis on histogram and use dict function as input

Tags: python, label

How can I use a dict from another function as input argument to histo below, and label the y axis with dict values (in addition to the x-axis)? Or is there a simpler alternative to this code at all?

```
def histo(his_dict = {1:1, 2:10, 3:10, 4:6, 5:5, 6:4, 7:2, 8:1} ):


    x_max = max(his_dict.keys()) + 2 #get maximum value of x
    y_max = max(his_dict.values()) + 2 #get minimum value of y
    # print line per line
    print ('^')
    for j in range(y_max, 0, -1):
        s = '|'
        for i in range(1, x_max): 
            if i in his_dict.keys() and his_dict[i] >= j:
                s += '*'
            else:
                s += '   '
        print (s)
    # print x axis
    s = '+'
    for i in range(1, x_max):
        s += '---' 
    s += '>'
    print (s)      

    # print indexes
    s = ' '
    for i in range(1, x_max): 
        s += ' %d ' % i
    print (s)

histo()
```

Comment: You are seem to be assuming somebody knows what your function is supposed to be doing, what "his_dict" means, and what your axis labels refer to.  Try to explain more what you're actually going for.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would just draw the histogram with [pylab](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

```
import pylab

pylab.hist([1,1,1,2,2,3])
pylab.show()
```

And instead of passing a dict, just pass a raw list of values.
The y-axis will be computed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've never tried Pylab before, but I will research on that. I would still like to know how to use a dict though if anyone has ideas...